# Need to rewrite question marks and equals signs in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

Rewritten my url. However I can still access rewritten urls with question marks and plus signs.

```
lovelakedistrict.com/lake-district-cottages/?cottages=2/
lovelakedistrict.com/lake-district-cottages/?cottages/2/
lovelakedistrict.com/lake-district-cottages/cottages/2/
```

The three urls above are the exact same page, I would like to properly re-write them so they  redirect to the correct structure (the last url) to stop duplication of webpages.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^.#?\ ]+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/

RewriteCond %1 !^include/
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^lake-district-cottages/cottages/([0-9]+) lake-district-cottages.php?cottages=$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/*([^=&]*[^=&/])/*(&+(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1/%1/?%3 [N]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/*([^=&]*[^=&/])/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1/%1/?%4 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/*([^=&]*[^=&/])/*=/*([^&]*[^&/])/*(&+(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1/%1/%2/?%4 [N]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\?[^\ ]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/*([^=&]*[^=&/])/*=/*([^&]*[^&/])/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

But I guess the easiest would be to use a more powerful language than mod_rewrite like PHP:

```
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
if (count($parts) === 2) {
    $path = rtrim($parts[0], '/');
    parse_str($parts[1], $params);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $path .= '/' . (($value === '') ? trim($key, '/') : trim($key, '/') . '/' . trim($value, '/'));
    }
    header('Location: http://example.com'.$path.'/', true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: the htacccess rules work well apart from when I try this for example
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/lake-district-cottages/?cottages=2/
it directs to
http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/lake-district-cottages.php/cottages/2/

(adds on the php extention)- can this be removed? thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @ajfmedia: That might be due to the order you use these rules. Make sure to put those rules, that cause an external redirect, before those rules, that just cause an internal redirect.

Comment: One more thing Gumbo, is there a way I can stop the rules affecting anthing in the results directory
eg http://www.lovelakedistrict.com/result/q=windermere/ because it messes up my search query string :(- although it does tidy them up!

Comment: @ajfmedia: Yes, you could either add the following condition to each rule: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/result/`. Or you put this rule in front of the other rules to skip them: `RewriteRule ^result/ - [S=4]`.

Comment: Hey Gumbo, sorry to bother you, can you look at something else for me?- I didnt want to post a new question because I feel like they are all to much of the same.